# Can I get a list of the values that are not functions in all of the program modules?

Tags: module, f#, namespaces

My F# program runs well but sometimes I find it difficult to understand the flow. I define values that are not functions in many modules. When these modules are opened these values are bound. I would like to obtain a list of all the names of non-function values and in which modules they were declared. Is this possible?

The example below may clarify the question.

```
module A =

    let i = 1
    let add x y = x + y


module B =
    let x = 99.9
    let sqr z = z * z

open A
open B

let y =
    add (float i) x 
    |> sqr

printfn "%f" y
```

Is there a function foo that would do the following?

```
let nonFuncVals = foo()
printfn "%A" nonFuncVals
// ["A.i", "B.x"]
```

Comment: Do you need a list of these values for any specific purpose? If you have let-bound values in modules but you don't want to pollute the namespaces where the modules are opened with these values, you should declare them as internal, e.g. ``let internal i = 1``.

Comment: If you are serious, the [FSharp.Compiler.Service](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/) should be able to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in support for this. Depending on how you work, you might be able to do this in some hacky way, but it is probably going to have quite a few limitations.

The following works on your example, when you run it using F# interactive, but I'm sure there are many ways in which it can break:

```
open System.Reflection

let nonFuncVals () = 
  let special = set [ "it"; "CheckClose"; "LastGenerated" ]
  [ for t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes() do
      if t.FullName.StartsWith "FSI_" then
        for p in t.GetProperties() do
          if not (special.Contains p.Name) then
            if t.FullName.Length <= 8 then yield p.Name
            else yield t.FullName.Substring(9) + "." + p.Name ]
  |> Seq.distinct

nonFuncVals()
```

The function looks at the currently defined types and uses the fact that F# Interactive puts generated bindings in types with names such as `FSI_0001`. This is, however, undocumented behaviour and it can change in the next version...